# Jenkins: How to avoid creating workspace on the P4 server?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

Whenever I create a new job on Jenkins, it creates 2 workspaces on the perforce server. (with a suffix -0 and -1)

Is it possible to tell Jenkins to only create a local workspace on the machine and not create the workspace on the Perforce server.

As I have many Jenkins jobs, it is soon going to be clutterd on the perforce server with so many workspaces.

Comment: What do you mean by "workspace on the Perforce server" ? In Perforce terminology a workspace (also named "client") is the metadata that keeps track of what you checkout (from where to where). This metadata is stored on the server and doesn't consume space you need to take care of. Only on the client the real data (file contents) are checked out.

Comment: But I ran created 10 jenkins jobs and suddenly there are 20 workspaces (2 each) due to these jobs. Isn't there a way to keep things pretty by skipping this client/metadata creation?

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is the reason, but the Jenkins P4-Plugin has to create 2 clients if there are parallel builds of the same jobs running. Since the perforce workspace also includes the definition of the checkout target there have to be 2 workspace declarations for concurrent builds.

Comment: @pitseeker this might be the reason. But I was not thinking 1 vs 2. I would like to have 0 workspace due to Jenkins.

Comment: Well, if Jenkins is supposed to checkout sources then it has create a dedicated workspace of course. Just don't care about it. It perfectly normal that a Perforce server has several thousand workspaces. No problem with that.

Comment: Most Perforce admins have a simple tool that they run routinely which finds and deletes old workspaces. Does your admin have that tool? If so, don't worry. If not, perhaps they should deploy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perforce is a centralized system where the central server is the source of truth for the state of each workspace.  It's technically possible to pull files from Perforce without creating a tracked workspace, and you could technically rewrite the Jenkins plugin to do this, but practically speaking that's like surfing Wikipedia via `curl` because you don't want to clutter your desktop by installing a browser.

My recommendation is to configure Jenkins to prefix all of its workspaces with a conveniently filterable string like `~jenkins~` so you can easily ignore them, and then to move on with your life.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking for is a single permanent workspace that survives the build, and no temporary workspaces. Bamboo can be configured to do things that way and it seems reasonable to ask for, and cuts down on some thrash.

Comment: OP said specifically "I would like 0 workspaces due to Jenkins", which is less than 1.  :) . Either way though I think you're better off dealing with the way it works than trying to rewrite it.  Having a few extra workspaces defined on the server just isn't a resource problem the way that most users instinctively assume it would be.

Comment: But it could be a time resource problem. Syncing a "permanent" workspace to the latest usually takes almost no time. Syncing two 700 MB workspaces from scratch every time you do a CI build might be considered a waste of time.

Comment: I don't know much about the Jenkins plugin, but I'd hazard a guess that one reason to not use one set of workspace files for everything is that you lose any sort of parallelism, which in a CI system that might be shared by thousands of users seems like it would be a pretty bad tradeoff for saving a bit of disk I/O.  (Somewhat orthogonal from whether to use multiple workspace specs, since you could in theory have one workspace *spec* and use `sync -p` to populate different roots -- I'd assume it's using `sync -p` anyway but I could be wrong.)

Comment: You might have something there. Atlassian Bamboo behaves this way with all source control systems except Perforce, specifically to deal with parallelism. Too bad, though, that they don't just let us choose what we want. Most builds aren't done in parallel, I'd wager.